# Collision between mhchem and mathdesign

Tags: fonts, pdftex, mhchem, mathdesign

Maybe related to a package database update to last versions, I have a collision between the `mchem` package and other font-related packages such as `mathdesign`. Whenever I try to use the command `\ce{}` to insert chemical equations, the following error appears:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text>
\inaccessible
l.10 \begin{equation} \ce{2Al+3/2O2->Al2O3}
\end{equation}
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
```

The minimun **not**-working example is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

The following line causes pdfLaTeX to fail:
\begin{equation} \ce{2Al+3/2O2->Al2O3}  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I have tried the following:

- Searching mhchem.sty to find `\def cs{`: it's not there.
- Reading exercise 27.2 of *The Texbook*: it just says to **not** omit the backlash and ends telling that you "Explain how to recover from this error..." (it's one of those marked with a curvy road sign, *for wizards only*").
- Changing the order of package loading.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling `mhchem`.

To no avail. Does anyone know about this problem? Is a bug of the `mhchem` package? and last but not least, can any of you advanced wizards point me in the direction to solve this problem?

Many thanks for reading so far =)

**EDIT:** I got in touch with Martin Hensel and looks like the problem is indeed in `mhchem`, he told me that some people reported similar problems and sent me an updated version of the package that did work. I suppose that he will update the repositories soon. =)

PS: Should a mod close this question?

Comment: This 'works for me' as you have written it. Is the code _exactly_ what you used to test? If so, could you post your log somewhere we can look at?

Comment: Ah, this shows up after update TeX Live - I'll investigate :-)

Comment: Could you post your edited-in information as an answer: I see that CTAN has an update which mentions fixing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that Martin has updated his package in CTAN, fixing the incompatibility.

Joseph Wright (who now I recognize as a very active member in LaTeX Community and the creator of `siunitx`, and happens to have a little rhombus by his name) has suggested that I post the updated info as an answer; as I don't know well the mechanics of stackexchage, I suppose this closes the question?

Thank you =)

*Edit: should I accept this answer?*

Comment: @JoreGT: You have to wait a couple of days, but then 'accepting' the answer would be great.